# Best way to use zlib from macOS Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, zlib

There seems to be a conflict between the version of zlib used in the SDK and what may exist on a user's machine. For example...

On macOS 10.11.6 and Xcode 8, the version of zlib used during compilation doesn't match the version of `libz.dylib` loaded at runtime. Specifically, the header file used during compilation is for zlib v1.2.8, but the dylib file loaded at runtime is for 1.2.5.

This can result is a runtime crash because it can attempt calling a function that doesn't exist in 1.2.5. The problem is the header (from the SDK) thinks we are using 1.2.8 so it will compile code that is 1.2.8-specific based on any `#if` defined for a version check.

What then is the best way to link against and use zlib?

Should I compile it as a static lib and ignore the OS supplied version? I am currently doing that and using 1.2.8 in my app, but it may be causing a problem for a user on 10.14.3. I am considering switching to a dynamic lib, but the above situation comes into play there too.

Comment: In my target's **Link Binary with Libraries** settings, I add `libz.tbd` (from the pop-up `+` dialog) and have never had any problems. My binary runs on 10.9 through 10.14.

Comment: The way to tell for sure is to print both `ZLIB_VERSION`, which is from the header, and the result if `zlibVersion()`, which is from the linked library. Are you doing that?

Comment: I have macOS 10.14.3, and what I see are symbolic links for 1.1.3, 1.2.5, 1.2.8, and 1.2.11, all pointing to the same actual .dylib file, which contains 1.2.11.